# Защита от SQL инъекций в jdbc java

Tags: java, безопасность, jdbc, preparedstatement, sql-injection

Часто вижу утверждения, что надо использовать `PreparedStatement` вместо обычного `Statement`, чтобы защититься от sql инъекций. Как он защищает?

Comment: Только нужно помнить, что 
подготовленные запросы, кроме вашего кода, проходят еще и
через сторонний (библиотеки и jdbc-драйверы).
И если в этом стороннем коде подготовленные запросы реализованы через обычные (все собирается обратно в строку),
то защиты от SQL инъекций не будет. Это довольно известная проблема 
[в мире PHP PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/8996454).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Коротко, для нетерпеливых:

При использовании `Statement` строки запроса и значений складываются.

При использовании `PreparedStatement` имеется шаблон запроса и данные в него вставляются, с отражением кавычек.

Ниже подробнее с примерами.

---

**Вступление.**

Имеем такую простую таблицу с данными.

```
+-----------+----+--------+
| userName  | id |  pass  |
+-----------+----+--------+
| admin     |  1 |  admin |
| user      |  2 |  pass  |
| chuchelo  |  3 |  elli  |
+-----------+----+--------+
```

Модель `User`, будет содержать имя и пароль, а так же метод логин, который спросит данные с консоли.

```
class UserLogin {
    String name;
    String pass;

    public UserLogin() {
    }

    public void login()  {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.println("user name: ");
            name = reader.readLine();

            System.out.println("pass: ");
            pass = reader.readLine();
       } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (reader != null)
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
```

---

**Метод, который будет работать с обычным `Statement`:**

```
UserLogin user = new UserLogin();
user.login();
try (Connection connect = MyConnection.getConnection()){
    Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT userName, id, pass FROM users WHERE userName='" + user.name + "' AND pass = '" + user.pass + "'";
    System.out.println(query);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

    while (resultSet.next()){
        System.out.printf("User: id=%d name=%s pass=%s\n",
                resultSet.getInt("id"),
                resultSet.getString("userName"),
                resultSet.getString("pass"));
    }
    MyConnection.closeConnect();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Теперь если мы запустим этот метод и введем в консоль данные без инъекции:

```
user name: admin
pass: admin

User: id=1 name=admin pass=admin
```

При этом сам запрос выглядит так:

```
 SELECT userName, id, pass FROM users WHERE userName='admin' AND pass = 'admin'
```

Если допустить ошибку в имени или пароле, то данные выведены не будет.

Теперь попробуем использовать инъекцию(`' or'1'='1`), т.е. введем такие данные:

```
user name: admin' or'1'='1
pass: blabla
```

То мы все равно получаем результат, несмотря на то, что пароль неверный:

```
 User: id=1 name=admin pass=admin
```

При этом сам запрос теперь выглядит так:

```
  SELECT userName, id, pass FROM users WHERE userName='admin' or'1'='1' AND pass = 'blabla'
```

т.к. выражение `or'1'='1'` всегда равно `true`, то даже без указания пароля мы получим все данные.

---

**Как от этого защитит `PreparedStatement`?**

Метод который будет получать данные из базы с помощью `PreparedStatement`:

```
UserLogin user = new UserLogin();
user.login();
try (Connection connect = MyConnection.getConnection()){
    String query = "SELECT userName, id, pass FROM users WHERE userName=? AND pass=?";
    PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(query);
    statement.setString(1, user.name);
    statement.setString(2, user.pass);
    System.out.println(statement);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

    while (resultSet.next()){
        System.out.printf("User: id=%d name=%s pass=%s\n",
        resultSet.getInt("id"),
        resultSet.getString("userName"),
        resultSet.getString("pass"));
    }
    MyConnection.closeConnect();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Все тоже самое, только заменили обычный Statement на PreparedStatement. Надеюсь вы на слово поверите, что при правильных данных мы получим верный результат, если нет то вот лог в консоли:

```
user name: user
pass: pass
User: id=2 name=user pass=pass
Запрос:
SELECT userName, id, pass FROM users WHERE userName='user' AND pass='pass'
```

А теперь попробуем использовать инъекцию:

```
user name: user' or'1'='1
pass: inject
```

И ответа не получаем, потому что запрос выглядит так:

```
  SELECT userName, id, pass FROM users WHERE userName='user\' or\'1\'=\'1' AND pass='inject'
```

Т.е. все кавычки были отражены слешем, инъекция не удалась.

---

Отличие `Statement` от `PreparedStatement`:

`Statement` - вы должны заботиться о кавычках в запросе и ставить их там где они нужны.

`PreparedStatement` - вставляет значения в запрос и за счет методов setString setInt и прочих. Он сам понимает где нужны кавычки, а где нет. Соответственно все входные данных оборачивает ими.

Comment: Очень красивый и ёмкий ответ, спасибо!