# Не обновляет данные в таблице MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Есть метод

```
public void onOK(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws SQLException, IOException {
        phone.setModel(txtModel.getText());
        phone.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(txtPrice.getText()));
        phone.setCategory(comboboxCategory.getValue().toString());
        phone.setDescription(txtDescription.getText());
        phone.setProducer(comboboxProducer.getValue().toString());

        try (Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()) {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            String query2 = "update phones set model = " + phone.getModel() + " where id = " + phone.getId();
            System.out.println(query2);

            statement.executeUpdate(query2);
        }

        onCancel(actionEvent);
    }
```

При выполнении этого метода пишет:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Unknown column 'ghjgjgjgjgjgjg' in 'field list'

Что это означает? Минут 20 уже не могу понять в чем причина

А если поле phone.getModel() имеет строку с пробелом, то пишет

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'G7dfgfdg where id = 4' at line 1

Comment: Это означает SQL-инъекцию.

Comment: Как правильнее?

Comment: Экранировать все данные, которые попадают в SQL-запрос, очевидно. Но как это делается в джаве я не в курсе

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо. На самом деле нужно было экранировать.

Comment: почитайте, я писал об инъекциях https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753823